# Ember View: Properties and/or functions? What's best?

Tags: ember.js

I have a pretty simple question regarding to custom properties and functions in Ember.View. I have a searchbox. If touchmove is triggered 10 pixel will be added to the margin-left. Sounds stupid? Yes it is, but it's just an example ;)

```
App.SearchboxView = Ember.View.extend({
    marginLeftProperty: function(){
        return parseInt(this.$().css("margin-left"));
    }.property(),

    marginLeftFunction: function(){
        return parseInt(this.$().css("margin-left"));
    },

    touchMove: function(e) {
        console.log(this.get("marginLeftProperty"));
        console.log(this.get("marginLeftFunction"));
        old_margin = parseInt(this.$().css("margin-left"));
        new_margin = old_margin + 10;
        this.$().css("margin-left", new_margin+"px"); 
    }
});
```

I would like to access a the margin by a separate function or property. Since I am not sure I tried both of them. A function and a property. I used console.log to check what works best.

---

```
console.log(this.get("marginLeftProperty"));
```

dragging the searchbox returns "0" multiple times although the margin is changing.

---

```
console.log(this.get("marginLeftFunction"));
```

this one is always returning the function itself, not the value.

So what is the "best" way to access this value? Is there a trick to run a function instead of returning it? Or can I update the property manually (I think it is cached by ember because it returns the initial value 0 but is not updated after the margin changed)

Comment: Okay, got it. The marginLeftProperty is working if I use property().cacheable(false) instead of only .property()

Comment: To get the return from `marginLeftFunction` go ahead and use `console.log(this.marginLeftFunction())`. `get` will return a function if that's what you're `get`ting.

Comment: Thank you @pjmorse. That was simple :)